# C# Retrieve data from database and display on textfield

Tags: c#

I have a Login form(named LoginForm) which the user needs their username and password. How do i get all the data from the row which that username and password came from and display it on textbox(es) on another form (named Form1) i made?

I would like to display the retrieved data on Form1_Load

Heres a part of the code from LoginForm

```
static string conString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Thalia\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EnrollmentSystem\EnrollmentSystem\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance =True";
SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(conString);

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataReader dr;
    // DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand readCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Username = @u and Password = @p", myCon);
    readCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u", txtUsername.Text);
    readCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", txtPassword.Text);

    myCon.Open();
    dr = readCmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        Form1 y = new Form1();
        y.Show();    
    }
    else
    {
        lblinvalid.Text = "Error.";
        // myCon.Close();
    }
    myCon.Close();
```

}

Form1 appears after a successful login, the details retrieved from the database should appear on load
here is my Form1(i have no idea what to put here)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: you want to create list of text boxes?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to create couple of property in the Form1 class and then set the value after initialising it.

```
              public class Form1 {
                  public string InformationToShow;
                  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                   {
                            //use the property here
                   }
              } 

               Form1 y = new Form1();
               y.InformationToShow = "I am here";
               y.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass "dr" through to the "Form1" class in the constructor (copy it into a member?? pass the reference through??). Then you can set the various fields in "Form1" to be values from "dr".

Comment: can you mark one of these as correct answers if they have solved your issue? Thanks, Mal

Answer (score 0):

Two options spring to mind:

1) You could add public properties to the form Form1 so you can pass values over, such as:
    Form1.MyCustomProperty = "Some Value"

2) Create a new constructor for Form1 which you could pass values over to:
    Form1 y = new Form1("Some Value");

On a separate note, you probably want to retrieve the data and close the DataReader before launching the form, otherwise it may be held open indefinitely, consuming resources it doesn't need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use static class.
Create one static class lets say "userInfo" and define all the fields in this class which exists in data-row.
Set all the fields data in this class then you can use this data any where in you application.